# Is there a word that describes people capable of picking up an accent by hearing?

Tags: word-choice, terminology, accent

A friend of mind told me about his accent teacher who picked up his accent (for a specific sentence) just after few times she heard him saying it, so I wonder if there is a word that describes this talent.
Thanks.

Comment: ***have an ear for something***: 
Fig. to have the ability to learn music or languages. *Mary has a good ear for languages.*
http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+an+ear+for

Comment: I never heard of an "accent teacher" before, but I suppose having such an ability *under conscious control* would probably be pretty useful for such people, so it could be called a "talent". In other contexts, good ***mimics*** such as [Mike Yarwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Yarwood) can use the ability to entertain others and earn a good living as impressionists. But I think an awful lot more of us just have a *tendency* to reflect the speech of our interlocutors without even being aware of it.

Comment: that accent teacher works a lot with actors

Comment: There are very few people who are able to pick up an accent _by any other means_ than hearing, so ‘person’ would be a possible answer…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, it is called ***speech imitation ability***. The person who has this ability is called a ***good mimic*** also.

> Speech sound imitation is a pivotal learning mechanism for humans. Vocal imitation provides a basis for acquisition of both languages and musical systems.
>
> Some people, on the other hand, are adept at vocal imitation and make a living mimicking dialects, speech characteristics, and foreign accents.
>
> <sub>*[ncbi.nlm.nih.gov](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3804907/)* / *Are you a good mimic? Neuro-acoustic signatures for speech imitation ability*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what "picking an accent" means. Probably you intend 'picking **up** an accent', in other words being able to imitate it.

This is a talent of **mimicry**.

Comment: updated to pick up. does mimicry capture the talent to pick up the accent immediately upon hearing it?

Comment: This part: "I don't understand what "picking an accent" means. Probably you intend 'picking up an accent', in other words being able to imitate it." should be a comment. No need to mention in an answer and you can suggest edits to the question also. For "mimicry", it would be nice if you can mention the source. "Mimicry" is used in biology also.

Answer (score 1):

By "picking up an accent by hearing," I take it that you mean someone who can hear someone speak and immediately determine where the person is from by the his idiolect (i.e., the person's own accent, word usage, and grammar).  If so, then the term you may be looking for is *phonetician*.

In the preface to his play *Pygmalion*, George Bernard Shaw, says that in his character Henry Higgins, there are "touches" of Henry Sweet, a somewhat prickly contemporary linguist and expert on phonetics, whom Shaw describes as the "best of them all," referring to the class of *phoneticians*.

In Act I, a number of people are taking shelter from the rain under the portico of a church -- a lady and her daughter, a note taker (who will turn out to be Henry Higgins), a gentleman (who will turn out to be Colonel Pickering), and a flower girl (who will turn out to be Liza).  The note taker accurately determines where the lady and her daughter live from their speech, and the following exchange takes place:

```
THE GENTLEMAN [returning to his former place on the note taker's
left] How do you do it, if I may ask?

THE NOTE TAKER. Simply phonetics. The science of speech. That's
my profession; also my hobby. Happy is the man who can make a
living by his hobby! You can spot an Irishman or a Yorkshireman
by his brogue. I can place any man within six miles. I can place
him within two miles in London. Sometimes within two streets.
```

Answer (score 1):

Mimetic or Mimesis (Mimetic Theory from Rene Gerard)

....the observable tendency of human beings to subconsciously imitate others and the extension of this mimesis to the realm of desire.

Comment: I don't know why this was given a minus, but I agree with the word or definition.